# PROMEDIO PREPONDERADO DATA STUDIO

Tags: formulas, google-data-studio

cual es la manera de poder hacer un promedio prepoderado en data studio ?

Ya que intento hacerlo pero me da error.. ya que no puedo agregar metricas en los campos..

Mi idea era hacer algo asi pero no me resulta posible..

```
CASE  WHEN FechaProduccion BETWEEN DATE(2022, 01, 01) AND DATE(2022, 08, 31) THEN 
IF(AHT_OBJETIVO_CURVA>=1,1,AHT_OBJETIVO_CURVA) / sum(Chats_MONTH) * 0.3333333333333333 + 
IF(RSAT_OBJETIVO_CURVA>=1,1,RSAT_OBJETIVO_CURVA) *0.3333333333333333 +
IF(REOPEN_OBJETIVO_CURVA>=1,1,REOPEN_OBJETIVO_CURVA) * 0.3333333333333333
```

PD.. el 0.03 lo tengo que utilizar ya que es el peso de los Objetivos dividio los mismos..

Pero hacer una ponderacion segun los cahts que tiene el objetivo ejemplo **Chats_MONTH** por ahora no puedo solcuinarlo.

De verdad Agradecedira mucho!
Saludos-.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la solución:

```
Sum(( Chats_MONTH * Cumplimiento Topeado y Objetivo )) / sum( Chats_MONTH )
```

Comment: Por favor, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [answer]. No olvides explicar cómo funciona tu código, y [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta.